# Connect to Devices on same wifi network IOS

Tags: ios, swift, smart-tv, wifi, dlna

i am going to create application which will connect to smart TVs on same wifi network.

[Here is link to  reference app](https://apps.apple.com/pk/app/tv-cast-screen-mirroring-app/id1470813786) which i want to create.

Apple provide following services to connect to devices:

1. NEHotspotHelper
2. Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC)
3. Peer-to-peer(Only for apple-apple)
4. NEHotspotConfiguration

Which one should i need to use and also any reference if you can provide.
I want to share picture and video on TVs as above reference app does.

i Tried **EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser** but this only shows homekit devices. i want to connect all TVs that support wifi.
I have gone through many links but could not find what i want.
I just want to know on which SDK/library should i work?

Comment: You can probably connect to DLNA-supported SmartTV. Check out the DLNA tag above for similar questions.

Comment: A TV might support DLNA, chromecast, miracast and probably loads of proprietary protocols. Connecting to "all TVs that support wifi" does not make sense.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen the reference application connects to all brands(type)TVs on same wifi network.(To all means every brand. it connects to one TV at a time)

Comment: Look, they _say_ their app connects to all TVs but they are lying. In reality they support some specific technologies (at least DLNA/UPnP is mentioned) that are available in some TVs.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen thank you, i have found solution which is DLNA as you mentioned.